# QT - Fill a QMap with only key, and then add values for each key

Tags: c++, qt, hashmap, qmap

I would like to know if is it possible to fill a QMap with only key, and then for each key add value.

for example, something like :

```
QMap<QString, QString> map;
map.insert("key", null (??));
```

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling a map with only keys is not possible, however you can initialize it with null strings as values.

Note that in Qt there is a distinction between empty strings and null strings.

I would therefore initialize each element of the map as

```
map.insert("key", QString()); // map of null strings
```

as opposed to

```
map.insert("key", ""); // map of empty strings
```

Comment: Thanks, it is was I needed

Comment: You are right, I expected the string to be null if you pass a string with only a null character in it. Alas, Qt doesn't make sense much of the time.

Comment: @dtech This is a QString feature (shared by other Qt types as well) that I ended up finding quite neat.

Comment: @dtech if you expect Qt to create a null string from an empty c-string, how would you create the empty string in the first place? It makes perfect sense as it is. I'm not sure if `nullptr` can be cast to `QString` as in `QString(nullptr)` should use the `QString(const char*)` constructor.

Comment: @xander - there is no such thing as an empty C string, `""` implicitly contains one single character - the null termination. You are effectively passing a null, the string length will be evaluated as a null too.

Comment: Also, why would you want to create an empty string in the first place? What is the intent here, because how would I do that depends on why I want to do that.

Comment: @dtech For me "" is still an empty string, it doesn't matter if the underlying data contains 1 char (`\0`) or 0. For `QString:isEmpty()` to return true it can be a null string (`QString:IsNull()`) or empty string, there are reasons to differentiate those states.

Comment: @xander I didn't say it is not beneficial to differentiate between empty and null, all I said it is logical to expect that passing C string with only a null should result in a null string. You can have a string that contains nothing but reserves space, that would be an empty string that is not null.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can fill it with empty string values, then simply change the strings:

```
QMap<QString, QString> map;
map.insert("key", "");

// and later

map[key] = "something else";
```